# Dataview.RowFilter resulting in Cannot perform '=' operation on System.String and System.Int32

Tags: vb.net, rowfilter

```
Dim sValue As String
sValue= DataBinder.Eval(idContainer.DataItem, "MyField").ToString.TrimEnd

'(i have a dataview dvMydataView)
dvMyDataView.RowFilter = "MyField2 = " & sValue 'Here, the "MyField2" datatype is string
```

If DataBinder.Eval(idContainer.DataItem, "MyField") datatype is int32 (contains a valid numeric value), then Rowfilter results in the following exception :
Cannot perform '=' operation on System.String and System.Int32

Clearly, it is expecting quotes before and after sValue

On the other hand if DataBinder.Eval(idContainer.DataItem, "MyField") datatype is string, though the value contained in it is a valid integer value, then there is no exception in the row filter statement.
This implies that it is not expecting quotes before and after sValue here.

What could be the reason for such a behaviour?

Comment: needs codeblocks edits to be clearer

Answer (score 1):

The `RowFilter` property contains what is effectively a SQL `WHERE` clause. ADO.NET objects only support a very small subset of SQL syntax but it still has to be valid SQL syntax. Just as you wrap double-quotes around a `String` literal in VB code, so you wrap single-quotes around a text literal in SQL code. You have no quotes around your value so it's not interpreted as a text literal.

```vb
dvMyDataView.RowFilter = $"MyField2 = '{sValue}'"
```

That's using string interpolation, which should be the preferred option in recent versions. You could use `String.Format` or basic concatenation too.

Comment: I don't know if I'd go as far as to say it's as sophisticated as an SQL WHERE or even that it has any more than a passing resemblance to SQL. A full rundown of the supported syntax and operations can be found in the documentation for the [DataColumn.Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-6.0) property